# Accessing Function of BLL in Presentation layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an Application where user can Register himself and after Registration he navigate to Home Page.I am doing this in MVC3 but by converting it into 3Tier.For this i have named the Original Project as Presentation and made the DAL and Added the Model Folder and DbContext as well into that and Deleted the Model From the Presentation.And now i have to create BLL where i want to write all the Logic for Insert,Delete and Update and want to access it in My Controller which is in My Presentation.How can i do this?
Please Guide me on this!!!

Comment: Insert,Delete, Update have no place in BLL. Actually from what I see, you don't really need a business layer. Just use the DAL directly from the controller

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are asking us to rewrite your whole solution for you?

There are many starter kits online that give you a hint on how to get things done.  There are many different ways to achieve the same result.  I'll give you a brief outline of how I do things.

For this example I will make reference to customers, you can modify it to fit in with your solution.

I have a solution called `MyProject.DomainModel`.  In this project I have my customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I have a project called `MyProject.EntityFramework`.  Here I have all my repository classes.  Example of a customer repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> FindAll()
{
     return DatabaseContext.Customers;
}
```

I then have another project called `MyProject.Services`.  A customer service would call your customer repository.  A service layer isn't allows needed but when I need some logic or need to call other repositories then I use a service layer.  This is how I would call a repository method from the service layer:

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
     IEnumerable<Customer> FindAll();
}

public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
     private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

     public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
     {
          this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Customer> FindAll()
     {
          return customerRepository.FindAll();
     }
}
```

You will see that the CustomerService constructor receives an instance of ICustomerRepository.  This is taken care of by a dependency injection framework like `Autofac`.

In your controller you will have a List action method that has a List view to display all your customers:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
     private readonly ICustomerService customerService;

     public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
     {
          this.customerService = customerService;
     }

     public ActionResult List()
     {
          IEnumerable<Customer> customers = customerService.FindAll();

          return View(customers);
     }
}
```

There is much more to it than this.  You will have to download some starter kits online and work through it to get you on the right path.  What I have given is just a general outline.

I hope this helps.